# Beam Dataflow Pipeline Table Creation Sink as Bigquery from GCS

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I want to create beam dataflow job to load data from GCS to Bigquery, I will have 100s of files from different folders in GCS in Parquet format, is it possible to load files from different folders in GCS and is it possible to create source dataset and tables in the beam code itself.

My end goal is to create pipeline to load data from GCS to Bigquery
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is a perfect fit for Dataflow. You can use `FileIO` to read from GCS and `BigQueryIO` to write to BigQuery.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate solution, You can use `gsutil`  to move all files from different GCS folders to one single folder. Then once you have all files in a single folder over GCS then you can easily Read data from GCS and Load it to BigQuery.